# Html5 тег video на мобильных

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Есть фон видео сделанный с помощью тега video с авто запуском.  Как можно не воспроизводить видео на мобильных? Так как скорость интернета может быть низкая.

Comment: вы его хотите вообще сносить или что?

Comment: Скрывать ccs'ом не вариант?

Comment: Да на мобильных и так блокируется автовоспроизведение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрыть с помощью CSS не хватит, видео будет грузиться, просто вы его не увидите.

Решение, это добавление тега video с помощью JS, после проверки размера экрана устройства.

```
w = screen.width,
if(w>750)
{
    document.getElementById("MyDivId").innerHTML= "<video>...";
}
```